# Chmod 640 for uploaded file after SUPEE 7405 patch

Tags: php, file, magento, patch

After installing the SUPEE 7405 patch, we noticed a problem uploading images from the admin. All file permissions are being set to CHMOD 640 which makes them inaccessible to all users.

Is there a solution that does not involve rewriting the /lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php file?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: Small note: You can change the chmod with PHP (as long as PHP has the permissions) `chmod($filepath, $new_chmod);` Though the files should be uploaded by the user/group of the webserver.

Comment: The solution below proves that this is a server related issue, partially. The solution doesn't completely solve all of the issues with the CHMOD 640 change of the SUPEE 7405 patch, but it does resolve a few of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new version of SUPEE-7405 has been released that resolves this issue:

http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405

> **Updated February 23, 2016**
>
> Updated versions of this release are now available. The updates add support for PHP 5.3 and address issues with upload file permissions, merging carts, and SOAP APIs experienced with the original release.

Note that even without the revised patch, you can fix the issue by using the recommended file permissions (see below).

---

Magento expects the webserver to own the site files:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html#privs-after

You can resolve this problem by making the webserver the owner of the files.

```
chown -R web-server-user-name magento/root/path
```

The webserver user name is commonly `www-data` or `apache`.

If you follow the instructions in the above link, the webserver will have read access to all files, and write access to media files and var files. This should be all you need for typical site operation. If you need to use Magento Connect you'll have to temporarily give the webserver write access to all files.

> All file permissions are being set to CHMOD 640 which makes them inaccessible to all users.

Only the webserver user needs access to the files. There is no need to grant any permissions to all users.

You may want to grant access to a specific user if, for example, you need to edit or upload files via FTP. In this case, what I do is set a user who owns the file system and set the files' group to the webserver:

```
cd magento/root/directory
 
# Set ownership 
# 'username' should be the file system owner username
# 'webserver' should be the webserver username
chown -R username:webserver .
 
# Give the user read/write access to all files.
# Give the webserver read access to all files
find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 2750 {} \; 
 
# Give the user and the webserver read/write access to var and media
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
chmod 2770 includes
chmod 660 includes/config.php
```

The above commands will give your file system owner read/write access to everything and the webserver read access to everything. The webserver will also be able to write to the media and var directories.

Comment: I never thought to look in this direction. I'll give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: NOTE: I've marked this as a solution, however, I still encountered issues when using this method. For example, we use a javascript image slider on our front page. After adding chown -R to the server, the image appears in the thumbnail view from the admin, but in the front-end (visitor/guest), the user stills recieves a 403 (forbidden) error when trying to view file.

Comment: @Jared That sounds like there is still a permissions issue. Does the webserver have read access to the image? Note that Magento can resize images, so the image displayed on the frontend is not necessarily the same image displayed on the backend.

Comment: You might  be right. I tested the solution on three modules: Adding a new image to an existing product failed to display in the admin, but appeared in the front-end. My custom module where the image/file is made available for download worked perfectly in both front-end and back-end. Finally, the third party front-page slider failed both, the front-end and back-end image tests. I've put our dev server in maintenance mode to perform a few more tests and confirm a few things. It does sound like a permissions issue though. Perhaps I missed another patch related change.

Comment: I have a solution, but it's specific to my server's environment and may not help other people out. This is in the right direction so I'm leaving this as the correct answer and will post my answer as well below.

Comment: If your webserver runs as nobody, are they any security implication in changing the group of all your magento files to no-group? Will this invalidate the whole point of the patch?

Comment: @Dom If only the webserver is running as nobody then I don't think there is any difference. My understanding is that `nobody:nogroup` is used for general, unprivileged access. If you have other processes running as nobody then they will have read access to all of the site files, including the local.xml file. This doesn't really have anything to do with the patch. See: APPSEC-1306 https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405

Comment: @mtinsley I guess I'm trying to understand what security enhancement the patch makes by making sure the permission for others is zero. I can understand denying executing the files that could be uploaded. If you end up having the files as phpuser:nogroup, then aren't you relaxing the  - others can't view the file - restriction that the patch enforces?

Comment: @Dom Before the patch, the permissions were set to 777 `chmod($destinationFile, 0777);`. Making it 640 addresses the issue. Relaxing it to 644 works as well, but is inconsistent with the [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). The patch is mainly meant to address the problem with the file being executable.

Comment: @mtinsley that makes sense now, thanks. I like your solution of using gid and changing the group of all files to the webserver, but I'm concerned that cPanel scripts would not expect this, so for now I've overridden the Varian/File/Uploader.php with 644 permissions. Given the outcry on the Magento forums, do you anticipate Magento will change the core file to 644?

Comment: @Dom Regarding cpanel, you still don't need to grant permissions to all users. With suPHP, PHP files are accessed as the file system owner and non-PHP files are accessed as the webserver. Regarding changing the permissions to 644, I'm not sure if they will or not. I don't think there is any use-case that can't be addressed by correcting the file permissions.

Comment: @mtinsley On my hosting environments, Apache runs as nobody, so for Apache to be able to serve uploaded images, those images either need have o+r permission or have to have no-group. My concern is that cPanel/WHM generates accounts where the webroot is owned and grouped with the account user, and I was wondering if the various cPanel/WHML scripts that run, require or expect this owner:group

Comment: @Dom To be honest, I'm not overly familiar with WHM and I tend to avoid it completely when it comes to Magento. You may want to try asking on server fault.

Answer (score 1):

We've solved the issue for our environments, however, I'm not sure how much help this will be for everyone else. Even though I'm not a network engineer, I will try to explain it. If enough people find this post helpful, I'll mark it as correct. Also, please note that even though the issue arose from Magento's SUPEE 7405 patch, the solution is Network based, not code based.

I believe the purpose of the chmod alteration in the patch was to prevent hackers from hijacking your images and storing sensitive data within them (the checkout header image hack for example). To prevent this hack, they limit all access to uploaded files/images via chmod 640.

With that said...

The latest patch to Magento 1.X seems to require an **environment configuration change**. As one of our network engineers said, they assume we are using Apache with mod_php, which reads and writes all files as the Apache user. However, if you are using fcgi or suphp, the files would be written as the domain user. Depending on your environment, you may need to add Apache to your groups and allow it to read the files.

Try the chown -R solution first, and if that doesn't work you may need to contact your host or add Apache to your "groups" so that it has owner access.

Comment: With suphp, I think you can just `chown -R user:user` where 'user' is whatever user the webserver is running as. I think this will be the solution for cpanel as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please go on this file

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

and just change line no 220 and change `chmod($destinationFile, 0640)` to `chmod($destinationFile, 0644)`

It's working.

Comment: Shame on Magento! This definitely should be a config option as not everyones setup is the same. As long as it's not, I'll grudgingly apply the core hack :/

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a good solution.

If you are unable to change the ownership (maybe because you are on a shared server) you can run cron jobs to change file permission on the newly uploaded files.

```
*/3 * * * * find /path/to/magento/ -type f -perm 640 -exec chmod 644 {} \;

*/3 * * * * find /path/to/magento/ -type d -perm 750 -exec chmod 2755 {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at this: https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/after-installing-SUPEE-7405-can-no-longer-add-or-change-images/td-p/26785/page/3

Changing Upload.php code worked for all my installtions.

```
To fix existing uploaded images, you need to change ALL existing uploaded images permissions (chmod) from 0640 to 0644.
To fix it for the future, you would need to edit /lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php and change the line from (after applying the patch)

chmod($destinationFile, 0640);

 to

chmod($destinationFile, 0644);

There is a similar one for directories that you'll need to change from 0750 to 0755.
```

Comment: please read the question. Modifying the lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php is not a good solution as it will break future patches. It's better as a temporary band-aid until a real solution is made public.

Comment: There is no need to edit core files, this can be done as an override. Copy /lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php to /app/code/local/Varien/File/Uploader.php and edit the copied file with the suggested permission changes above. This should be the preferred solution as the answer from @mtinsley above doesn't address some common problems with server configuration.

Comment: I try to change Uploader.php but don't work for me. I also try to add the same file to /app/code/local/Varien/File/ . But no change it uploads again image with 0640. Are there more files to fix?

Comment: Please note that this is not a good solution. It undermines the purpose of the security patch which protects your images from having credit card information stored in them.